# Button to alert to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with javascript/html. I have made an button that opens a alert but then I want 
to go to a different webpage when I click ok in the alert. Is this possible? Here's what I got.

```
<button href="../index.html" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);">Nej</button>
```

edit: Im having a new problem. I have 4 "pages"(don't know what to call them)that I want to link to them all together. You answer a question and an alert shows up redirecting you to the next page. I get the 
first link to work but not the other ones.

This is what I used for the first link but it does not work when I have multiple of these in place.I tried giving them different tags/names but that didn't work.

```
<button href="../index.html" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);">Nej</button>
<script>
function confirm_alert(element) {

redirect = confirm("confirmation for redirecting?");

if(redirect) {
  window.location = element.dataset.href
}
</script>
```

English is not my native language so I'm sorry for all the spelling errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to happen if they hit cancel?  Are you trying to make it so the user confirms following the given link?

Comment: The confirm() returns true or false. So, you can test for that and do one action or another.

Answer (score 3):

That's not valid markup.

Buttons do not have an `href` attribute. You may want to use a link `<a>` tag, or you'll need to use javascript to redirect the user using `window.location = 'http://google.com'`

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```js
function confirm_alert(element) {
  
    redirect = confirm("Do you want to redirect?");
  
    if(redirect) {
      window.location = element.dataset.href
    }
}
```

```html
<button data-href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);" class="knap3" >button</button>
```

Since you are using a button, its better define a `data-*` attribute instead the `href` one because the directive `href`doesn't exist in a button widget. Then in the method `confirm_alert(this)` we pass the element as parameter, getting its `data-href` attribute and use the `confirm()` method to confirm if user want to be redirected. This method returns a boolean, confirming whether user accepts or not. Then, the `window.location` redirects the user.

**References**

Data-* attributes - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Window.location - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location